# Error when trying to deallocate pointer of char array: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, boost-asio, delete-operator

I'm writing a C++ program that sends and receives images using Boost.Asio.

When compiling I don't get errors, but when executing and having sent an image the program that receives the image crashes giving the following error message (in Visual Studio 2012, Windows 7 32bit):

> Debug Assertion Failed:
>
> Program: […]`\DataSender.exe`
>   File: `f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgdel.cpp`
>   Line: `52`
>
> Expression: `_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)`

I read packages the size of 4096 bytes into a pointer to a char array while there are still incoming bytes to read. In the final looping—if there are less than 4096 bytes to read—I delete the pointer and create a pointer to a char array the size of the remaining bytes. Until here it still works.

But when I try to delete the char pointer array again at the end of the loop (in order to create a new char pointer array with standard size 4096 for the next incoming images), the program crashes.

Here is my code's excerpt in question:

```cpp
char* buffer = new char[4096];
```

[…]

```cpp
int remainingBytes = imageSize;
```

[…]

```cpp
// read data
while( remainingBytes > 0 )
{
    boost::system::error_code error;

    // use smaller buffer if remaining bytes don't fill the tcp package
    // fully
    if( remainingBytes < 4096 )
    {
        delete[] buffer; // this one doesn't give an error
        bufferSize = remainingBytes;
        char* buffer = new char[bufferSize];
    }

    // read from socket into buffer
    size_t receivedBytes = socket.read_some(
            boost::asio::buffer(buffer, bufferSize), error);
    remainingBytes -= receivedBytes;

    // count total length
    totalReceivedBytes += receivedBytes;

    // add current buffer to totalBuffer
    for( int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++)
    {
        totalBuffer.push_back(buffer[i]);
    }

    // if smaller buffer has been used delete it and
    // create usual tcp buffer again
    if( receivedBytes < 4096 )
    {
        delete[] buffer; // here the error occurs
        bufferSize = 4096;
        char* buffer = new char[bufferSize];
    }
}
```

I ran the same code also on a Debian GNU/Linux 7.2 64bit machine, which returned the following error, at the same position in code:

> `*** glibc detected *** ./datasender: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000002503970 ***`

I assume I'm doing something wrong when deallocating the char pointer array but I haven't figured it out yet.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `delete[buffer];` now this is curious, don't you want `delete [] buffer;` instead? (Just asking, I'm a bit confused by your statement). Oh and by the way, the `buffer` you allocate in the if statement is local to the if scope. You're leaking here.

Comment: Use std::vector.  1) It is safer and easier to use and 2) it probably would run faster than the new/delete gymnastics you're doing now.  A buffer resize using vector will not go through the hoops of calling new[]/delete[] if the buffer happens to be smaller.

Comment: There's really no reason to resize the buffer to make it smaller. Just keep track of how much data was received, and only read out that much.

Comment: @JBL: Oops, that has just been a typo. In the actual code it's `delete[] buffer`. But thank you, I wasn't aware it makes a difference if I'm declaring something inside or outside of a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually deleting twice the buffer when `remainingBytes` and `receivedBytes` are less than 4096.

Indeed, you're deleting `buffer` once, then allocate memory into **a local `buffer`, not the outer one**.

Then, when you delete `buffer` in the second if block, you're deleting a second time the same buffer. The allocation you've made in the if scopes are memory leaks. These aren't the same variables.

When you do

```
char* buffer = new char[bufferSize];
```

in your if scopes, you're creating a new variable, not allocating memory into the outer `buffer` variable. Thus, you're leaking, and not allocating memory into the buffer you just deleted.

Without looking further, you should remove the `char*` in front of `buffer` in both if blocks and then continue debugging.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Now it's working. I thought there is only a difference between local and global variables inside and outside of functions—but come to think about it, I knew that the iterator of a for-loop is local but it hasn't been that clear to me obviously.

Comment: Two things: 1) Think about scopes for variable names visibility. Not only functions, but if-blocks, loops, etc. 2) As many others have pointed out, you should definitely consider using a standard container like `std::vector` for what you're doing. You'd have spared a lot of memory shenanigans that ended creating this problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use std::vector instead:

```
#include <vector>
//...
std::vector<char> buffer(remainingBytes);
bufferSize = remainingBytes;
//...
while( remainingBytes > 0 )
{
    boost::system::error_code error;

    // use smaller buffer if remaining bytes don't fill the tcp package
    // fully
    if( remainingBytes < 4096 )
    {
       buffer.resize(remainingBytes);
       bufferSize = remainingBytes;
    }

    // read from socket into buffer
    size_t receivedBytes = socket.read_some(
            boost::asio::buffer(&buffer[0], bufferSize), error);
    remainingBytes -= receivedBytes;

    // count total length
    totalReceivedBytes += receivedBytes;

    // add current buffer to totalBuffer
    totalBuffer.insert(totalBuffer.end(), buffer.begin(), 
                                          buffer.begin() + receivedBytes);

    // if smaller buffer has been used delete it and
    // create usual tcp buffer again
    if( receivedBytes < 4096 )
    {
        buffer.resize(4096);
        bufferSize = 4096;
    }
}
```

There will be no memory leaks.

Also, I think your code has a bug in that you are supposed to copy only the number of received bytes (the return value of the read_some() function).  Instead you assumed that bufferSize characters were returned.